# XNA 2D Transformation

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, transformation

I have actually the following map (isometric projection), and I can move/zoom/rotate without problem with matrix transformations (SpriteBatch): [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQjWP.png).

And I wanted to know if it was possible (if so, how), to get the following result, without referring to 3D: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACkes.png).

All suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: without 3d hardly. you can try to scale down tiles that are far and make bigger that are close. but then you will need to calculate position between them to fit them close to eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be a huge pain in the ass, especially but I think it is at least possible if you don't change the viewing angle.

Some ideas:

Make each tile its own little image unit.

The more far back the tile is from the camera, lower its layer priority when you draw it so that it gets blocked by tiles in front of it. Also you will have to figure out an algorithm that correctly sizes the tiles based on their distance. This algorithm will have to be more and more precise the closer you want to get the tiles, but there should be some mathematical/geometric formula that can do it automatically.

You quite literally CANNOT rotate the camera at all, unless you want to have separate sprites for every single angle for every single tile.